# How can I execute a shell command just before login screen?

Tags: script, monterey, restart, login-screen

I apologize if the question has already been asked. macOS Monterey.

For a few days now, the blinking cursor of the login screen is not blinking anymore, so I can't type any character and I can't logon. Anyway, I can connect to the Mac via ssh. Typing as root the command:

```
killall -HUP WindowServer
```

the graphic server restarts and the blinking cursor now reappears, so I can enter username and password to log on it (see animated GIF).

[image]

My question is:

Where can I put this command to run it *before* login, just after graphic server loading?

Comment: How would this command know whether the login screen is stuck or not? You may end up in an endless restart loop... To look at the main issue: Does it happen all the time (i.e. also directly after a reboot) or only when waking up from sleep?

Comment: Well, I can say that this happens every time I power on or reboot the Mac. I would like to place the above command somewhere, so it can be executed after graphic environment is loaded.

Comment: The trouble is that the WindowServer is the Graphic environment so how do you know if the WindowServer is working or not. So you need to fix the issue that makes the cursor disappear.

Comment: In the case of no cursor does hitting tab key change anything - it should change which field has the focus.

Comment: Hitting the Tab key does nothing, cursor still unavailable in the two fields. Only after killing the graphic server via ssh I can enter user/password and have a successful login and then the Mac works flawlessy.

Comment: So I reinstalled OSX Monterey froma a USB external drive using the Recovery Disk Assitant: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433?locale=en_US and finally the cursor on login page in now active again.